# NPM/GIT style powershell module

Tags: powershell

How can one create a powershell module that can be called like npm or git ?

Example:

```
git commit SomeFile.py
```

Git is the powershell module you want to use.
Commit is the action you want to execute
And then you have a list of arguments.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a param block with 2 parameters:

1 parameter that has `Position=0`, and 1 that supports `ValueFromRemainingArguments`:

```
function gitlike
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory,Position=0)]
        [ValidateSet('commit','pull','push','status','etc')]
        [string]$Command,

        [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
        [string[]]$Arguments
    )

    # parse $Arguments in here
    # or
    # Invoke-YourCommandSpecificThing @Arguments
}
```